# My loop won't end

Tags: vba, excel

1) I have a porblem with my FOR loop. I goes *ad infinitum*. And this is the first problem of mine on which I ask your help.
2) Second problem is that I don't know how to add more then one conditon in "If"
My questions are in the code as comments.

```
Sub Repurchase_upload()

Dim Worksheet As Worksheets
startrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(10, 1) 'Here I denote 1
endrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(11, 1) 'Here I denote 1000
For x = startrow To endrow

            If Cells(x, "A").Value <> "DU" Then 'I would like it to look like that: 'If Cells(x, "A").Value <> "DU" or "DR" or "EK" Then' but I don't know how to do this 'or'
            Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents
            End If 'And here it won't end...
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple condition is easy to implement:

```
For x = startrow To endrow
    If Cells(x, "A").Value <> "DU" Or Cells(x, "A").Value <> "DR" Or Cells(x, "A").Value <> "EK" Then 
        Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents
    End If
Next x
```

For the infinite loop I don't know, it seems fine to me... isn't simply too slow ?
Maybe you should disable the screen updating before calling `ClearContents` a thousand times e.g. :

```
Sub Repurchase_upload()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Disable screen updating

    Dim Worksheet As Worksheets
    startrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(10, 1) 'Here I denote 1
    endrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(11, 1) 'Here I denote 1000
    For x = startrow To endrow
        If Cells(x, "A").Value <> "DU" Or Cells(x, "A").Value <> "DR" Or Cells(x, "A").Value <> "EK" Then 
            Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  'Re-enable screen updating

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing the multiple value test is to use the select statement as shown below:

```
Sub Repurchase_upload()

    Dim Worksheet As Worksheets
    startrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(10, 1) 'Here I denote 1
    endrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(11, 1) 'Here I denote 1000
    For x = startrow To endrow
        Select Case Cells(x, "A").Value
        Case "DU", "DR", "EK"
          'Do nothing
        Case Else
            Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```